# How to get the important places in the travelling direction between two points in google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, maps

I want to get all the important places in the travelling direction from one city to another.
For Ex., Someone is travelling from Mumbai to Pune, I want to show the restaurants, Hotels, shops etc., on the driving direction to the user based on their needs using javascript google maps api v3.

I have checked in google maps documentation and the map utilities but in vain.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance